# iOS scrolling with fixed position

Tags: javascript, ios, css, css-position

I've read all the articles I can find and still can't figure this quirk out.

Setup:
What we have is a fixed positioned nav that slides down from the top. You can scroll up and down the nav just fine on android, all desktops, and 99% of the time on iOS devices

Problem:
On new iOS devices, when you scroll to the top of the window, but not enough to make the "page bounce", you can't scroll up or down for about a second or until the device is rotated.

Anyone run into this or any have ideas on how to fix it? The nav is rendered on the GPU, I've tried show/hiding the nav on scroll/touchstart/touchend, I've tried all the tricks my brain can come up with. Please help. I'm dying.

And of course, I can't show you my code because of my company...

Comment: Can you show image/gif what you actually mean?

Comment: You can show the pieces of code for sure. Even if it's under NDA. No one knows where you took that piece of code. If you copy that code into your own project then copy from own project to Stackoverflow, do you think it counts as your own code or code of the company?

Comment: having a gif or a video would be ideal. each of us may interpret your words in our own way. and it will be a loop of useless comments/answers. hope you understand it.

Comment: Is the scroll event being debounced? If not try that and increasing the scroll position range in which the "page bounce" effect is triggered.

Comment: So, I think I know what is happening. When you scroll to the top and get the "page bounce", everything is golden. When you scroll to the top barely so you don't see the page bounce, it still makes you wait for the page bounce to be over, even though you don't see it, before you can scroll again. @WildBeard do you have an example of what you are talking about? We aren't scroll jacking or anything.

Comment: Is the page bounce you're referring to on iOS devices when you pull down too far and the page separates from the browser's nav bar or is it your page being pushed down by the appearance of your site's nav?

Comment: @WildBeard Its the effect where the page separates from the nav bar with that "elastic" feel. Its on bg's mobile site. its live...i know you.